# Como modificar la contraseña de un usuario en Django?

Tags: python, django, backend

- Buenas, soy nuevo en Django y he estado haciendo un proyecto para el registro de usuarios. Hice un modelo basado en `AbstractBaseUser` y `PermissionMixin` que luce de la siguiente manera :

  ```
  class Usuarios(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # local attrs
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    edad = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    # base attrs
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('email', 'nombres', 'apellidos', 'edad')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    # manager
    objects = UsuariosManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"
  ```
- Este modelo lo enlace al `AUTH_USER_MODEL` del archivo `settings.py` (`AUTH_USER_MODEL='Base.Usuarios`), de modo que sera el modelo que se use para la creacion de superusuarios desde la terminal. El problema surge cuando trato de actualizar un usuario a traves de un `UpdateView`, todo radica en que, la nueva contraseña se tendria que actualizar usando `set_password` para que se encripte, pero por alguna razon que desconozco, esto no funciona ... Aqui esta la vista:

  ```
  class UpdateUser(UpdateView):
    template_name = "Base/update_user.html"
    context_object_name = "user"
    model = Usuarios
    success_url = BASE_SUCCES_URL
    form_class = AddUsuariosModelForm


    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user = self.object
        user.nombres = data['nombres']
        user.apellidos = data['apellidos']
        user.edad = data['edad']
        user.email = data['email']
        user.username = data['username']
        if user.password != data['password']:
            user.set_password(data['password'])
            print(user.set_password)
        user.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
  ```

Comment: Qué error te muestra?